# Seeking Online Large Format Map Printing Service based in North America?

Tags: printing, maps, online, north-america

I am looking for an online large format printing service.

My requirements for such a service are:

- large format (ANSI E +/-)
- high resolution
- double sided
- paper of different quality
- based in North America
- completely online service:

  - online ordering;
  - online upload; and
  - online payment.

Any answer should supply a link to the service's website and evidence that the service nominated meets the requirements listed above.

Comment: Please do not repost a closed question without addressing the issue(s) which caused it to be closed.

Comment: well i did and then i was referred to the link in this post stating that i wasn't following the rules. if someone could list exactly what rules i am not following from the included link i will be sure to fix them.

Comment: as for what i am following from that link to make my question better: "inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”" i am asking why.
"tend to have long, not short, answers" i am encouraging others to submit their experiences and what they were offered creating longer answers.
"have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone" i am being impartial and constructive in adding to a knowledge base
"invite sharing experiences over opinions" i am inviting people to share their experiences

Comment: "insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references"i hope that they include links and specifics from their experiences
"are more than just mindless social fun" na

Comment: i understand that subjective questions are discouraged but i have done everything that i can to make this as objective as possible, and i know that this kind of information would benefit this community, especially because of the way that most business is conducted now.

Comment: Never mind addressing the issues, you should not be reposting closed questions period. Edits can be made to the original to bring it in line and have it reopened. Deleting and reposting is simply attempting to bypass site moderation and could result in punitive action. The main SE is also not the place to discuss (re: argue) extensively whether or not you agree with site moderation. That is best left to chat or the meta GIS.SE.

Comment: I think @ChrisW is right.  My understanding is that the SE algorithms that determine question bans include deleted questions so deleting and reposting should be avoided at all costs, and replaced by question editing to convince the community that a question should be re-opened.  I have edited your question into a form where I am comfortable for it to remain open.

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, it is best suited on GIS SE chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well chat is dead, i never even knew that chat existed until yesterday, i don't think that the community as a whole uses chat, i am looking to get exposure for this question, not have it ignored for days, the nature of this site is that if it isn't addressed quickly it falls through the cracks

Comment: The [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) is certainly under utilized.  It may be timely to review and refresh some of the Meta discussions about when it should be used: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat-rooms?sort=votes

Answer (score 1):

I have used this company before for printing both large scale maps for wall hanging (government maps) and for producing mailers that went with a specific public works campaign.  They meet all your criteria.  Our experiences were just fine but we had completed all the design work ourselves and were simply having things printed in formats and in quantities that our in house department couldnt handle. As for price, I have no idea, but since we are a govt agency and work on bids I would think they had to be somewhat reasonable

http://www.csiprinting.com/

What services they say they do in their page:

Offset Printing
Digital Printing
Variable Data Printing (VDP)
Bindery - Binding & Finishing Services
Pre-Press
Mailing Services
Fulfillment Services

Comment: i am looking more for a completely online service. ie order online, upload online, and pay online.